# Ear vs multimodule Packaging strategy

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I develop in house Java EE applications.  They all share core set of functionality such as JPA `Entities (Employee.class), Session Beans (EmployeeService.class), Filters (Authenticate.class), Logging (Log4J2)`,  etc...

I created a `Java Utility` project and packaged these classes `com.mydomain.mylastname.core.(filter|domain|loggin)` into a .jar.

Then I'll create a Dynamic Web Project using JBoss Central `start from scratch`

I've been including the `core` as a POM dependency. Is this the correct way or should I be doing a multimodule or ear?

I ask because I have another case where the webapp project keeps expanding with more functionality which I have been separating with package folders in the same Eclipse project.

```
com.mydomain.mylastname.functionality1
com.mydomain.mylastname.functionality2
com.mydomain.mylastname.functionality3
```

I think it makes more sense to reorganize and move each functiality package into its own Eclipse/Maven project. That way I don't have to redeploy a ton of unchanged source code if only one piece updates.

But then how do I package them all into one deployable app/frontend? As an EAR or MultiModule?  Each functionality is basically a pull down in a navigation menu on a webpage. Perhaps I'm making this too complicated and the simplest way is to have an HTML front end that simple points to each separately deployed application... but then my menu bar needs to be maintained in all three apps. I'd like to share all the (JSF) templating, css, images too.

any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a personal choice, but having written projects based on multi modules and dependencies I am more inclined in using dependencies.

My reasoning is that:

- Dependencies make for faster build time, since they are already built.
- Dependencies don't have to be changed (parent pom version) every time the parent pom project is changed
- Review for dependencies is simpler, since it won't be included in the review of the parent project (if you change the version)
- You project upload and download (git here) will be faster since dependencies will only be downloaded as needed (once you ran maven for the first time to download the dependencies), whereas modules will be deleted and re-built every time you hit `mvn clean verify` on the parent, which will slow you down.

To your second question: how to deploy them.

If they have to run as modules (ears) then the strategy would be to isolate the dependencies as much as you can into reusable components that can be used by a very basic web shell that can stand them up behind a web server. For example, you could have a module that loads the dependency.

Another alternative would be for you to create a dependency that IS an ear file, and have a maven assembler that packages the dependency as an app. That might be simpler than defining a thin shell for your dependencies. Here's a reference on how to use the assembler plugin to create your apps from dependencies: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

EDIT:
Calendar, photoshare, chat, etc...

How they interact with each other goes far beyond Maven and modules/dependencies. For example, is versioning important? Can you deploy a Chat version 4 against the Calendar version 3? Do they share the same database? What are the requirements for uptime on the database? Is it a distributed application?

The list goes on and on and a simple answer becomes harder and harder.

Supposing you possess the infrastructure that supports all of the above, and all you are looking for are guidelines, then I would say that Calendar, Photoshare, Chat, are actually services with a established contract. In that case I would make them into different projects for the simple reason that it would be easier for different teams to work independently on them. I am considering here that, as the functionality of these services grow, you will need dedicated teams, and for that the best alternative are projects. Nothing to do with Maven, just time to market.

Comment: I should clarify my second question, 'The packaging of functionality' - the functionalities are not dependent on each other as the common core stuff is to all my projects.  I talking about creating an online app such as a blogging system and one functionality is a calendar, another is a photoshare, a third is a chat tool.  Would you create separate Eclipse maven projects or would all this be in the same project and separate the code using Java packages?

Answer (score 1):

This is your basic question if I have understood correctly : There are a lot of independent packages in your web app project. You are not sure if you want to have them as separate maven modules.

Here are a few points to consider:

- You ought to build the entire application artifact as single unit of deployment artifact. Even if there is a single line of change. This is okay.
- your application lib folder or maven dependency can contain many other libs - all of this can potentially be packaged into the deployment artifact. Here the libraries are not changed or source managed. They are just packaged with your application, with a known a version
- You can push common library / utility jar type code to your core module or other module and manage that source code as a separate maven module
- Even if your application source code reaches 100s of modules, it should still be easily to manage with source control systems like git, svn etc. As long as the lifecyle of the code (build,test, release) is same you can keep them as an unit.
- If you wish you can break your application code in 100s of maven modules each of which would be  required to built as an aggregated multi-module maven build, each time you need to deploy your code. And then you need a overall packaging module to package all the 100 artifacts in a ear or war or as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think we must first be clear about the terms multimodule and ear. A multi module is a Maven project structure, where each module generate its own artifact. An ear is an enterprise archive and can be the result of one of the modules.

Choosing your structure depends on release cycles. If all artifacts are always released together, you should put them in a single multimodule project. If one of the artifacts, for instance a utility-jar, is used by multiple projects, then don't use it as part of the multimodule project.